# IE Button click (on loop) with VBA

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

I'm having issues with executing the following task:

1. ***Working -*** Open IE and navigate to the intranet webpage (Its a database)
2. ***Not working -*** Click "Delete" button for first row of data
3. ***Not working -*** Wait for IE to refresh and
4. ***Not working -*** Click "Delete" button for second row which is now first.

I want to execute a click-loop that goes through the entire webpage searching for "Delete buttons". Using `GetElementByID` gives me a `RUn Time Error 424 Object Required` Error.

This is where I'm getting stuck at. Appreciate your help!!!

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    Sub Website()

        Dim IE As Object, Doc As Object, UserName As Object, Password As Object, strCode As String

        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
        IE.Visible = True
       ' IE open webpage page

          IE.Navigate "http://abc.com.au"

            Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

  End Sub
```

Comment: You have nothing inside your loop.

Answer (score 0):

do you use IE.Document.GetELementByID???

there has to be a Document in between.

and you should perhaps handle the error if it doesn't find an element.